# How long is the Touch ID authentication period?

Tags: ios, touch-id

I am wanting to prompt my user with Touch ID each time some event happens.  However, I noticed that if the events are close enough together, it won't give them the system prompt again.  It will just recognize that they recently auth'd, and then evaluates the policy as a success without them needing to give their thumbprint.

Does anyone know the official length of time an auth is good for before the user has to give their thumbprint again, after giving it the first time?  Documentation?

Let me know if any clarification is needed to my question.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I am curious to understand, what kind of an implementation would require multiple touch id prompts at the same time?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/lacontext/1622329-touchidauthenticationallowablere ?

Comment: @matt That seems super close.  But the code inline documentation (LAContext.h) states that only applies to lock screen auth, not auth within an application.